# Screen flicker on fullscreen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen, flicker

I am using javascript fullscreen API. Everything works fine and in all browsers as well except for IE < 11 which is OK. The transition to fullscreen is very smooth in Windows Safari, seems to be fine in FF and but in chrome, opera and chromium, the transition is very absurd.Most of the times, the screen just below the browser seems to appear for a moment and then transition to the fullscreen happens. It flickers too much which is very distracting and not a good UI experience. I noticed something similar in youtube as well that too only in the above mentioned browsers. Is there a way the transition can be handled or at least the flicker can be controlled?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I had this issue too. Try to hide the body tag while the screen gets fullscreen. It helped me.

Comment: hide the body tag and show it when fullscreen is done?

Comment: @JoãoMosmann hey i tried this...it doesn't seem to work...